# Mudar nome apresentado em coluna em gráfico javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html5

gostaria de saber como posso mudar o nome (series) apresentado ao passar o mouse na coluna do gráfico. 
Pesquisei e não consegui obter resposta. 
Grato por quem conseguir me ajudar.
Segue o código:

```js
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
  chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    type: 'column',
    options3d: {
      enabled: true,
      alpha: 6,
      beta: 16,
      depth: 100,
      viewDistance: 200
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Clientes'
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: 'Gráfico demonstrativo'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      depth: 25
    }
  },
  series: [{
    "colorByPoint": true,
    data: [{
      "name": "Coluna 1",
      "y": 500.94,
      "drilldown": "Coluna "
    }, {
      "name": "Coluna 2",
      "y": 106.4,
      "drilldown": "Coluna 2"
    }, {
      "name": "Coluna 3",
      "y": 1000.5,
      "drilldown": "Coluna 3"
    }, {
      "name": "Coluna 4",
      "y": 144.0,
      "drilldown": "Coluna 4"
    }]
  }]
});

function showValues() {
  $('#alpha-value').html(chart.options.chart.options3d.alpha);
  $('#beta-value').html(chart.options.chart.options3d.beta);
  $('#depth-value').html(chart.options.chart.options3d.depth);
}


$('#sliders input').on('input change', function() {
  chart.options.chart.options3d[this.id] = parseFloat(this.value);
  showValues();
  chart.redraw(false);
});

showValues();
```

```css
#container,
#sliders {
  min-width: 310px;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#container {
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
<div id="sliders">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Series também tem a propriedade name, é só colocar.Ex:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
  chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    type: 'column',
    options3d: {
      enabled: true,
      alpha: 6,
      beta: 16,
      depth: 100,
      viewDistance: 200
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Clientes'
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: 'Gráfico demonstrativo'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      depth: 25
    }
  },
  series: [{
    "name": "Teste",
    "colorByPoint": true,
    data: [{
      "name": "Coluna 1",
      "y": 500.94,
      "drilldown": "Coluna "
    }, {
      "name": "Coluna 2",
      "y": 106.4,
      "drilldown": "Coluna 2"
    }, {
      "name": "Coluna 3",
      "y": 1000.5,
      "drilldown": "Coluna 3"
    }, {
      "name": "Coluna 4",
      "y": 144.0,
      "drilldown": "Coluna 4"
    }]
  }]
});
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, era isso mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode mudar colocando depois de `series: [{"colorByPoint": true,` `"name": "O que vc quiser aqui",`